# Haskell Map Tree

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, map-function

I got a little problem which i cannot really solve. I want to map a function over a tree. However, while it compiles it gives out various errors when i want to use it. My idea is that I run "mapTree (+1) someTree" and it adds 1 to every value

My data structure:

```
data BinTree a = Leaf | Branch (BinTree a) a (BinTree a) deriving Show
```

My function:

```
mapTree func Leaf = func []
mapTree func (Branch left a right) = Branch (mapTree func left) a (mapTree func right)
```

If someone could give me a hint what I am doing wrong...

Comment: What is the error you get? Can you understand it?

Comment: `func []` will not be a tree. You surely want `mapTree func Leaf = Leaf`

Comment: there is also an error in your second line - not a compile-time error, but a logical error that will stop the function working as intended. I'll leave you to figure that one out :)

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! Yeah i found the logical error too, had to run the function over the value too of course...

Comment: As a general suggestion, when defining a top-level function always start from writing its type. That will make GHC know what you intend to do, and consequently produce better error messages.

Comment: what errors? when you're using it *how*? include full info in the question body please.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to my first answer I want to say, that, if you want to apply some function with `a -> b` type to some value with `t a` type (in our example `t` equals `Tree`), usually you might want to implement `Functor` instance for your type (but just a function in small tasks is also fine). Here is `Functor` implementation for `Tree`:

```
instance Functor Tree where
  --fmap :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
  fmap f Leaf                  = Leaf
  fmap f (Branch left a right) = Branch (fmap f left) (f a) $ fmap f right
```

As you can see, `fmap` is like your `mapTree`, but now you have `Functor` type class, it's more suitable way to do things like that, because `Functor` instance may be useful in future to implement another type classes.
Examaple of usage:

```
*GHCi> fmap (*2) $ Branch (Branch Leaf 7 Leaf) (-3) Leaf
Branch (Branch Leaf 14 Leaf) (-6) Leaf
```

Comment: Or you can just write  `instance Functor BinTree where fmap = mapTree`

Comment: Or you can just write `deriving Functor` after the data declaration, and the compiler will write your code for you ;).  (It's good to do it yourself a few times like this first, until you start getting bored)

Answer (score 1):

As chi indicated, it's almost always best to start with a type signature:

```
mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
```

If you'd done so, you'd have gotten two type errors, each of which points to a different mistake in your code. The first one:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( .code.tio.hs, .code.tio.o )
```

.code.tio.hs:6:21: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Tree b’ with actual type ‘b’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          mapTree :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
        at .code.tio.hs:5:1-39
    • In the expression: func []
      In an equation for ‘mapTree’: mapTree func Leaf = func []
    • Relevant bindings include
        func :: a -> b (bound at .code.tio.hs:6:9)
        mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b (bound at .code.tio.hs:6:1)
  |
6 | mapTree func Leaf = func []
  |                     ^^^^^^^

This one comes about because the first case is supposed to produce a `Tree b`, but applying `func` to an argument can only produce something of type `b`.

The second one:

```
.code.tio.hs:6:26: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘[a0]’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          mapTree :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
        at .code.tio.hs:5:1-39
    • In the first argument of ‘func’, namely ‘[]’
      In the expression: func []
      In an equation for ‘mapTree’: mapTree func Leaf = func []
    • Relevant bindings include
        func :: a -> b (bound at .code.tio.hs:6:9)
        mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b (bound at .code.tio.hs:6:1)
  |
6 | mapTree func Leaf = func []
  |                          ^^
```

This happens because you apply `func` to a list of some type when `func` is expecting an argument of type `a`.

Suppose you fix these errors by changing the first case to

```
mapTree _func Leaf = Leaf
```

(I've prefixed `func` with an underscore. By convention, this suggests that it's intentionally unused in this case. If you enable compiler warnings, which you should, this will prevent GHC from warning you about the unused variable binding.)

Now you'll get a new and different error:

```
.code.tio.hs:7:65: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          mapTree :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
        at .code.tio.hs:5:1-39
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          mapTree :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b
        at .code.tio.hs:5:1-39
    • In the second argument of ‘Branch’, namely ‘a’
      In the expression:
        Branch (mapTree func left) a (mapTree func right)
      In an equation for ‘mapTree’:
          mapTree func (Branch left a right)
            = Branch (mapTree func left) a (mapTree func right)
    • Relevant bindings include
        right :: Tree a (bound at .code.tio.hs:7:29)
        a :: a (bound at .code.tio.hs:7:27)
        left :: Tree a (bound at .code.tio.hs:7:22)
        func :: a -> b (bound at .code.tio.hs:7:9)
        mapTree :: (a -> b) -> Tree a -> Tree b (bound at .code.tio.hs:6:1)
  |
7 | mapTree func (Branch left a right) = Branch (mapTree func left) a (mapTree func right)
  |                                                                 ^
```

This is because you forgot to apply `func` to the value stored in the node. You needed to turn an `a` into a `b` and you forgot.

Answer (score 0):

For your type of tree such function will look this:

```
mapTree func Leaf = Leaf
mapTree func (Branch left a right) = Branch (mapTree func left) (func a) (mapTree func right)
```

Your mistake is that you can't apply such function as (+1) to the empty list. Function has to be `a -> b` type. When you meet a `Leaf`, you can't do anything with it, because in your implementation  Leaf doesn't contain any value, so we just return the `Leaf`. The single place, where we can apply our function is the center of the `Branch`, that's why I added applying this function to the value in the `Branch`

Here you can find examples of working:

```
*GHCi> mapTree (+1) $ Branch Leaf 1 Leaf
Branch Leaf 2 Leaf 

*GHCi> mapTree (+1) Leaf
Leaf
```